# Where can I find authentic translation source of Manusmriti?

Tags: manu-smriti

I want to find an authentic translation source of Manusmriti(where I can not only learn the outer meanings but also the inner ones)
Can I find it anywhere?

Comment: Try this version https://www.kritinova.in/collections/pbb/products/manu-smriti-hindi-kritinova

Comment: There is not one. All versions have been poluted to some degree.

Answer (score 1):

You can find it [here](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi)

Word of warning, Manu speaks in very ambiguous terms, so don't take his words at face value. Also, while the Manusmṛiti is mentioned a lot in cannon scripture, it is never truly endorsed (not including unendorsed quotes that contain a bunch of other, problematic stuff)

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi

Answer (score 0):

https://archive.org/details/dr.surendrakumar/page/n191/mode/2up?view=theater

Here Dr Surendra (he was head of department of sanskrit at MDU,rohtak) critically examined every verse of Manusmriti and explained which verses are interpolated . Though it is your opinion whether Manusmriti is interpolated or not and whether reasons provided by author for interpolation are right or wrong  but good thing is that Dr Surendra 's translation is quite apt even of those verses which he called interpolated.